# Why I can't access my nodejs local server from iOs simulator

Tags: ios, node.js, http

I am trying to make an http request from my xcode to my local server running on nodejs. The following in a part of my iOs code.

```
  let url = URL(string: "http://localhost.com/signup")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
    }

    task.resume()
```

I recieve the following the response

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be 
found.
```

I receive the first error if I use localhost.com and I receive the second error if I change the request to www.localhost.com

Answer (score -1):

in this case you have to use your IP to get access to your localhost

ex: `let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.105/signup")!`

so Instead of using (localhost.com/...) you have to set the IP of your computer where you have LOCAL SERVER.

Comment: Change the IP with yours, dont use 192.168.1.105 is just an exemple of local IP